# Chrome - disable Flash Player popup

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, chromium

Is there a way how to get rid of the annoying Flash Player popup in Chrome? I don't have flash installed and do not want to have.

[image]

Version 25.0.1364.160 Ubuntu 12.04 (25.0.1364.160-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)

Comment: Can you share a couple of links that show this pop-up and that don't require signing in?

Comment: @vasa1 see http://www.lidovky.cz/

Comment: Any more info on this? This happens with Chromium (v22.0 on Raspbian/Debian 7.8). For example in Google Analytics.